# Algorithm for testing a sure victory

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I am trying to write an algorithm in Python for test sure victory in my game.

The function looks like this:

```
check(num, options)
```

**num -** Number of circles at first

**options -** list of options that each player has to remove in turn.

Each player in turn removes a certain number of circles (according to the options he has).

The last player who drew the circles won.

Now I want to check if the first player always win like here that num=5 and options = [3,1]:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/i4qt5]

I started trying to solve this and where I came:

```
def check(num, options):

    options.sort()
    options.reverse()

    if num == 1:
        return True
    if num == 0:
        return False

    for i in range(len(options)-1):
        if options[i] == num:
            return True
        if options[i] > num:
            continue
        return check(num - options[i], options) and check(num - options[i+1], options)

    return check(num - 1,options)
```

Comment: Do you want to know if there is a winning strategy for a player or do you want to know if a player always wins no matter what he or the opponent does?

Comment: @SaiBot I want to know if a player always wins no matter what he does

Comment: in case of `check(6, [1, 3])` the 2nd player always wins. Proof: if player 1 draws 3, so does player 2 (and he could also choose to draw only 1 which also wins). If player 1 draws 1, we have the case above with exchanged players. Hence it depends :-)

Comment: I want to check if the first player always wins (given that he plays correctly)

Comment: Uh... what's your question?

Comment: He wishes to know if, given a current number, by only being allowed to subtract the numbers in the `options` array, he'd be assured to win everytime, no matter how he plays.

Comment: @IMCoins Yeah but what's the question? What do they want from us?

Comment: For me, it was pretty clear. He wants to test `sure victory` in his game. i agree with you that he didn't say that his function didn't got it right, but... for me, as we're talking algorithms, it is implied.

Comment: @IMCoins If they think they didn't get it right, they should tell us *why* they think that. Probably with an input that they get wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had fun writting this.

Tell me if you have any special cases that won't work with this.

Your main error was that you didn't take into account the fact that **the other player would play**. The trick I am using for this is a **xor logic gate**. The `<currentBool> ^ True` just reverses the `<currentBool>` state. So, in case we want to return True, and we would be playing, we just return our state (as it is `True`), otherwise, the opposite.

However, if it is the enemy turn to play, and he wins, it would return `False`, but in case he loses, it will return `True`, hence a win for you.

```
def check(num, options, currentTurn=True):
    #   If for some reasons, you want to sort in reverse
    #   You should do it like this.
    options.sort(reverse=True)

    #   However if it is 0, the current player obviously lose.
    if num == 0:
        return currentTurn ^ True

    for i in range(len(options) - 1):
        #   If the option gives currentPlayer the win...
        if options[i] == num:
            return currentTurn

        #   If the option is superior, can't use it.
        if options[i] > num:
            continue

        #   If we can subtract, then, we do ! And recursively
        #   go on to the next stage.
        return check(num - options[i], options, currentTurn ^ True)

    #   If the current player can't play, or hasn't won yet, he lost.
    return currentTurn ^ True
```

Comment: check(9, [1,2,4]) return true and it's need to return False

Comment: @YairB. Why do you accept and keep it accepted if you know it's wrong?

Comment: Keep checking, it does work. I deleted one of your condition that I thought I corrected, but was still wrong. You can try and think about this problem yourself though. :)

Comment: Fails `check(2, [2, 1])` and `check(3, [1, 2])`, returns `True` for those.

Comment: I will delete this answer, so it is not still checked as correct, so you can give your answer if you have one. I will still find my own just for my fun though.

Comment: Hmm, I do have one and I think it's good, but I don't want to post an answer under this no-question question...

Comment: Well, anyway I can't delete my answer because it's been validated and I'm busy with something else ;) I came very close to a conclusion but work calls !

Answer (score -1):

You are almost right.
For the non-trivial case you need to check if you can move in at least one losing state (False if I read your code right).

So you can code it like

```
if num == 0: return False
return any([not check(num - x, options) for x in options if x <= num])
```

This will be slow for large values of num because you repeat the checks. You can speed it up by memorizing the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help .. but it does not exactly work
check(9, [5,4,1]) 
player2 can win and the function return True..